# Sending value from jquery to php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm learning jquery and ajax. I have tried the following code, to post value to php from jquery. But it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what mistake am I doing here, and what is the solution.

I just want `value1` to be printed by the PHP server side code, with that value being sent by the Jquery based client side code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Practice 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['data'])) { 
        $data = $_POST['data']; 
        print( "data is: $data" ); 
        return; 
    } 
?> 

<body onload='process()'>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.post(window.location, {'data': "value1"}, function (data) {
        $('#response').text(data);
    }); 
    </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need an element with the ID of response in which to output your data, also the process function is undefined.

Comment: Try to debug using alert(data); then do other work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output to an element that doesn't exist '#response', also the process function is missing.

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
</head>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['data'])) { 
        $data = $_POST['data']; 
        print( "data is: $data" ); 
        return; 
    } 
?> 

<body>
<div id="response"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $.post(window.location, {'data': "value1"}, function (data) {
            $('#response').text(data);
        }); 
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting a response? If so, what? If not, have you checked developer tools to see if you're getting an error?

Comment: Are you getting a response though, I.E is anything appearing on screen?

Comment: No, nothing on the screen.